# WPF .Resx editor for localization

Tags: .net, wpf

I am looking for a simple tool that allows the translators to edit .resx files, in order to translate the applications' texts.

Visual Studio's Windows Resource Localization Editor is unable to edit these files, unlike Winforms applications.

Any suggestions?

---

**Edit**: I've found a nice free [tool at CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ZetaResourceEditor.aspx?msg=3220081) that does excatly what I needed, including simultanously editing multiple resources files and adding keys to all files at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heya... I have used [ResX Editor](http://www.tallemu.com/oasis2/file/joannes_vermorel/resxeditor/resxeditor_v1_2_zip/110430) in the past to do this...

I like it because it is very simple.

If that doesnt do the trick you can go to Code Project and do a search, there was also a few "projects" on thre that achieve similar things but I found them to advanced for my purposes... and of course Code Plex is sure to have a few as well.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. SourceForge Download link : sourceforge.net/projects/resx

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Winres.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bxdx003%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> The Windows Forms Resource Editor, Winres.exe, is a visual layout tool that helps localization experts localize Windows Forms user interface (UI) resources used by forms. The .resx or .resources files that are used as input to Winres.exe can be created using a visual design environment such as Microsoft Visual Studio. For information on deploying resources in .NET Framework applications, see [Resources in Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f45fce5x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).